# Missing values not identified in R

Tags: r, na

I want to define missing values as 99. I run the dataset as follows:

```
nameofdataset.csv <- read.table(file = "nameofdataset.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".", na.strings = c("99"))
```

Using the table command function, we can still see that the missing values are not excluded.
What is wrong with my code or dataset?

Thanks!!

```
> table(nameofdataset.csv$nameofvariable)

  1   2   3   4   5  99 
131 357 246 312 107  13 
>
```

Comment: Likely because your data is being read as numeric and not as string. If you want to turn 99 to NA, run `nameofdataset.csv$nameofvariable <- dplyr::na_if(nameofdataset.csv$nameofvariable, 99)`

Comment: Ok, thanks! This worked!